# Drive not connecting after power outage

Tags: mount, lsblk

I have a raspberry pi with two external hard drives. the electricity went off today and after that i couldn't enter the rpi. what i ended up doing was to remove the flash card and enter it in another computer where i could change /etc/fstab so it doesn't mount /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1. Then the rpi could start fine. but the two external hard drives are not mounted now. And they dont show up in /dev/sda1 or /dev/sdb1. They dont appear in lsblk. If i uncomment the mounting of those drives in /etc/fstab, i cant restart the rpi anymore. If I do i get "The root account is blocked".

I dont know how to mount those drives anymore. I have been trying to run fsck, but it uses /etc/fstab and fsck just complains about how its ignoring the two mounting lines in /etc/fstab.

How can I connect to those drives?

The following is the suspicious dmesg logs:

```
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
.
.
.
.
.not responding...
.not responding...
```

Comment: Do the drives show up on another PC? Do you happen to have the `nofail` option activated for said drives?

Comment: I took one of the drives and plugged it into another computer and it worked right away. I don't know what the nofail option is.

Comment: `nofail` is an option you may set in `fstab` (4th field) so that the booting may continue even if the device fails mounting (see `man fstab`). Like this you may uncomment the lines but still boot the Pi. Question: The drives of course do have their own power supply, yes?

Comment: Yes I have a special power source for the two drives.

Comment: I changed the /etc/fstab so that it contains /dev/sdb1 /media/dirname ext4 nofail. I then rebooted it and that surprisingly worked. But there is still nothing in /dev/sdb1. I stil can't find the drive.

Comment: Is this independent from which USB port you use? Any change when plugging it in and out after booting? Does the Pi recognize other USB-Devices (e.g. a thumb drive or a keyboard)?

Comment: Yeah i have a keyboard connected to it that works fine. I also tried switching the external drive and the keyboard (usb portwise), and the keyboard continued to work and the external drive continued to not be found.

Comment: in /var/log/messages i get logs saying its spinning up, both /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. But later it says that they are not resonding.

Comment: Can you add those messages to the question? Also, when you mount them on another computer, do you actually see the contents?

Comment: There is this splitter connected to the rpi. which has 4 usb ports, and has its own power supply. the drives dont work when i connect through it anymore. But the drives work when i connect directly to the rpi. I'm gonna buy a new usb splitter tomorrow and see if that works. Maybe the power outage damaged the usb splitter when it comes to power hungry devices like external drives.

Comment: Yeah i see the contents of the drive. I added the logs to the question.

Comment: I bought a new usb splitter and now it works.